# Exceptions when installing lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, lxml

On Mac OS 10.14.6, I'm trying to install lxml for Python 3.6 with:

```
> STATIC_DEPS=true easy_install-3.6 lxml
```

I get this exception:

`Exception: Command "./configure --prefix=/private/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/build/tmp/libxml2" returned code 1`

Here's the entire trace I get:

> Searching for lxml Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
>   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/a8/73d795778143be51d8b86750b371b3efcd7139987f71618ad9f4b8b65543/lxml-4.5.1.tar.gz#sha256=27ee0faf8077c7c1a589573b1450743011117f1aa1a91d5ae776bbc5ca6070f2
>
> Best match: lxml 4.5.1 Processing lxml-4.5.1.tar.gz Writing
>   /var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/setup.cfg
>   Running lxml-4.5.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir
>   /var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/egg-dist-tmp-mnc4h10m
>   Building lxml version 4.5.1. Latest version of zlib is 1.2.11
>   Downloading zlib into libs/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz from
>   https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz Unpacking zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz into
>   build/tmp Latest version of libiconv is 1.16 Downloading libiconv into
>   libs/libiconv-1.16.tar.gz from
>   https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.16.tar.gz Unpacking
>   libiconv-1.16.tar.gz into build/tmp Latest version of libxml2 is
>   2.9.10 Downloading libxml2 into libs/libxml2-2.9.10.tar.gz from http://xmlsoft.org/sources/libxml2-2.9.10.tar.gz Unpacking
>   libxml2-2.9.10.tar.gz into build/tmp Latest version of libxslt is
>   1.1.34 Downloading libxslt into libs/libxslt-1.1.34.tar.gz from http://xmlsoft.org/sources/libxslt-1.1.34.tar.gz Unpacking
>   libxslt-1.1.34.tar.gz into build/tmp Starting build in
>   build/tmp/zlib-1.2.11 Checking for gcc... Compiler error reporting is
>   too harsh for ./configure (perhaps remove -Werror).
>   ** ./configure aborting. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 157, in save_modules
>       yield saved   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 198, in setup_context
>       yield   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 248, in run_setup
>       DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 278, in run
>       return func()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 246, in runner
>       _execfile(setup_script, ns)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 47, in _execfile
>       exec(code, globals, locals)   File "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/setup.py",
>   line 245, in    File
>   "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/setup.py",
>   line 153, in setup_extra_options   File
>   "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/setupinfo.py",
>   line 82, in ext_modules   File
>   "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/buildlibxml.py",
>   line 391, in build_libxml2xslt   File
>   "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/buildlibxml.py",
>   line 330, in cmmi   File
>   "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/buildlibxml.py",
>   line 320, in call_subprocess Exception: Command "./configure
>   --prefix=/private/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/build/tmp/libxml2"
>   returned code 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/easy_install-3.6",
>   line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
>   line 2265, in main
>       **kw   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py",
>   line 148, in setup
>       dist.run_commands()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py",
>   line 955, in run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py",
>   line 974, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
>   line 410, in run
>       self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
>   line 665, in easy_install
>       return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
>   line 695, in install_item
>       dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
>   line 876, in install_eggs
>       return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
>   line 1115, in build_and_install
>       self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
>   line 1101, in run_setup
>       run_setup(setup_script, args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 251, in run_setup
>       raise   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py",
>   line 99, in **exit**
>       self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 198, in setup_context
>       yield   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py",
>   line 99, in **exit**
>       self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 169, in save_modules
>       saved_exc.resume()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 144, in resume
>       six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py",
>   line 685, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 157, in save_modules
>       yield saved   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 198, in setup_context
>       yield   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 248, in run_setup
>       DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 278, in run
>       return func()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 246, in runner
>       _execfile(setup_script, ns)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py",
>   line 47, in _execfile
>       exec(code, globals, locals)   File "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/setup.py",
>   line 245, in    File
>   "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/setup.py",
>   line 153, in setup_extra_options   File
>   "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/setupinfo.py",
>   line 82, in ext_modules   File
>   "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/buildlibxml.py",
>   line 391, in build_libxml2xslt   File
>   "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/buildlibxml.py",
>   line 330, in cmmi   File
>   "/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/buildlibxml.py",
>   line 320, in call_subprocess Exception: Command "./configure
>   --prefix=/private/var/folders/yd/szy02nx52b912gvn2qhh8nb40000gq/T/easy_install-_ctp1edv/lxml-4.5.1/build/tmp/libxml2"
>   returned code 1

any help will appreciate!
tanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, you might install lxml with one of these commands:

$ apt-get install python-lxml

$ easy_install lxml

$ pip install lxml

Comment: Thank you! Looks like easy_install is what I've got in my setup. However, I have two versions of Python. How would I indicate to install for my Python 3.6 install?

Comment: STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip3.6 install lxml